# Not all attributes are displayed in uiautomatorviewer or Appium pagesource

Tags: android, appium

I'm not sure if this is a bug but we have an app for which our dev team is appending an automationID attribute to each element. The specifications reference this ID and as part of our TDD practice we are attempting to build our tests using these ID's as locators. Unfortunately we can't use the actual ID field. Our problem comes where the AutomationID is not being displayed in our Appium pagesource of the app or in uiAutomatorviewer. Does anyone know how to expose this attribute?

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 0):

You can set content description to every object:

1. in the layout xmls: `android:contentDescription=""`
2. in the code for example:  `textView.setContentDescription("")`

to access there fields by Appium in java:

```
 driver.findElement(s)ByAccessibilityId("id");
```

Comment: Note that content descriptions are intended for supporting app accessibility using screen readers, so you should use proper descriptions of the content.